# How to know in which item a button was clicked

Tags: java, android, layout

So far i have a list view with a custom adapter, and each item in list has a button.
Im really confused; Im trying to do the following:

When user clicks on button(a delete button) in item in the list, i want to know in which item button was clicked so i can know which item to delete-how do i implement this? Ive seen something about setting tags, but Im still very lost.

I have also tried to reach the button from the list layout from my main activity, and cannot reference it.

please can you give me a detailed  description on how to do what i want to do thanks.

**ADDED adapter code:**

```
public class LocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
String [] n;
Context context;
String[] a;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public LocationAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] names, String[] addresses) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    n=names;
    context=mainActivity;
    a=addresses;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return n.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView name;
    TextView address;
    ImageButton ib;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, null);
    holder.name =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    holder.address =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextAddress);
    holder.ib = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
    holder.name.setText(n[position]);
    holder.address.setText(a[position]);
    holder.ib.setTag(convertView);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+n[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: Basically the onClickListener should be implemented inside the Adapter's getView which has the position parameter. Can you post your Adapter code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an `OnClickListener` for your `delete` button.

When the `delete` button is clicked, remove the row in the data source at `position`, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, null);
    holder.name =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    holder.address =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextAddress);
    holder.ib = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Delete);
    holder.name.setText(n[position]);
    holder.address.setText(a[position]);
    holder.ib.setTag(convertView);

    //Add this for on-click of delete button
    holder.ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         //Delete the row in your data source specified at position

    });

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+n[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detail, now quick question, i defined a ListView called locations in my main activity that gets data from this adapter, so how do i call locations.remove() if locations isnt known from the adapter class?

Comment: @Isaac If the Adapter is an inner class of the Activity, you can have a function in your Activity that removes the row, and call that function from the delete button OnClickListener.  You will probably want to change your data source to be an ArrayList instead of an array, since you can easily add and delete from an ArrayList.

Comment: oh maybe i was doing it wrong the whole time because i created a seperate class.....

Comment: @Isaac I would recommend making the Adapter class an inner class in the Activity, it would make deleting rows with your `delete` button much easier.

Comment: @ Daniel Nuget and how would i set locations to LocationAdapter if it is out of scope and is class?

Comment: @Isaac I assume that you already have code that successfully set the adapter for the `locations` ListView in your main activity.  If you move the LocationAdapter to an inner class of your main activity, it should still be in scope.

Comment: thanks i figured it out. BTW you are sickest SO user ever you wre an amazing help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this inside your getView() method of adapter.

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               System.out.println("button : "+position+ " clicked");
               // Do you code here.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `onClick` in the `getView`.

Example :

http://jmsliu.com/2444/click-button-in-listview-and-get-item-position.html

Theres a lot of tutorials for this out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SeekBarAdapter {private SeekBarListener mListener;
private ClickListener mListenerClick;
public interface SeekBarListener {

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser, int positionInList);

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar, int positionInList);

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar, int positionInList);
}

public interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v, int positionInList);

}

public listAdapter getAdapter(Context context, ItemPhotoEffect itemPhotoEff) {
    return new listAdapter(context, itemPhotoEff);
}

public void setSeekBarListener(SeekBarListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener listener) {
    mListenerClick = listener;
}

public class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private onSeekbarChange mSeekListener;
    private onClickChange mImgClickListener;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> itemsList;
    private Bitmap imgIcon;
    private ArrayList<Integer> positionProgress;
    private ArrayList<ColorEffectItem> colorItem;

    public listAdapter(Context context, ItemPhotoEffect itemPhotoEff) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (mSeekListener == null) {
            mSeekListener = new onSeekbarChange();
        }
        if (mImgClickListener == null) {
            mImgClickListener = new onClickChange();
        }
        this.itemsList = itemPhotoEff.getSeekBarItem().getIconSeekBar();
        this.positionProgress = itemPhotoEff.getSeekBarItem()
                .getPositionProgress();

        // if (itemPhotoEff.getSeekBarItem().getColorItem() != null) {
        this.colorItem = itemPhotoEff.getSeekBarItem().getColorItem();
        // }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (itemsList != null) {
            return itemsList.size();

        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        // if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbar_adapter_layout,
                null);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.seekbar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        holder.colorbutton = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.colorImage);
        holder.ln_img = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ln_colorimg);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        // } else {
        // holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        // }
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(itemsList.get(position));

        if (positionProgress.get(position) != null) {
            holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.ln_img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.seekbar.setProgress(positionProgress.get(position));
        } else {
            holder.ln_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.colorbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(this.colorItem
                    .get(position).getRcolor(), this.colorItem
                    .get(position).getGcolor(), this.colorItem
                    .get(position).getBcolor()));
        }
        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
        holder.ln_img.setOnClickListener(mImgClickListener);
        holder.seekbar.setTag(position);
        holder.ln_img.setTag(position);
        return convertView;

    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    ImageView colorbutton;
    LinearLayout ln_img;
}// This is class you need to know which button has been click
public class onClickChange implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        if (mListenerClick != null) {
            mListenerClick.onClick(v, position);
        }
    }

}

public class onSeekbarChange implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        int position = (Integer) seekBar.getTag();

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onProgressChanged(seekBar, progress, fromUser,
                    position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        int position = (Integer) seekBar.getTag();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        int position = (Integer) seekBar.getTag();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar, position);
        }
    }
}}
```

You can use mycode. Implements interface OnclickListener in your adapter.
And then implement in activity:
+ PositionInList use if you have than 1 button in row.

```
adapter.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int positionInList) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("", "Click on position in list" + positionInList);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Array. Array has fixed length so you cannot exactly remove its element. 
You need to use ArrayList in place of Array and implement ViewHolder pattern correctly:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
//merge both the content of a and n into one object "Item"
//and use ArrayList

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Holder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.name.setText(getItem(position).name);
       ...
       holder.root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            items.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
       });
     return convertView;
}
```

If you want to set clickable on the whole row with then you need to put the root element inside the ViewHolder.

```
class Holder{
   TextView name, address, ...;
   LinearLayout root; // or any Layout which is the root container of your row
}
```